# Exception Using chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In Chrome Manifest V2 I was able to easily capture the desktop. Attempting this in Manifest version 3 I have had no luck. I feel I may be missing something here in attempting this in Manifest V3.

I have been using this as a reference. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/

My manifest has these permissions granted to it

```
"permissions": [
    "idle",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "alarms",
    "desktopCapture"

],
```

This is the sample code I have been testing just to see if I can get the screen selector to come up. I have not included the tabs.tab as this is labeled as optional and I wanted to see if I could have the plugin trigger the screen recording feature on its own.

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen"], (streamID, options) => {console.log(id)});
```

I have been attempting to have this run in my background.js file.

Each time it runs chrome crashes completely with no errors given.

Reviewing the crash dump I can see the following information.

**Exception Code:** 0xC0000005

**Exception Information:** The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

Comment: C0000005 is a very bad error in the engine itself. You should report it to the Chromium team (check first if a bug ticket for it exists already).

Comment: I'm having the same error, I created this bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1271590

Comment: I should have followed up before. I found an existing bug and updated my information to it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1257659&can=2&q=desktopCapture

Answer (score 0):

**I solve it this way for Manifest v3.**

It was giving me errors too. When I checked the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/desktopCapture/#method-chooseDesktopMedia), chooseDesktopMedia it wanted three parameters.

1. DesktopCaptureSourceType[]
2. Tab
3. Callback Function

I see in your question your have put **1** and **3**. I did the same it was giving me errors. So I made sure I get the active tab first before calling **chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia** in the background script.

So the code looks like this

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, (tabs) => {
      if (tabs.length) {
        const tab = tabs[0];
        var pending = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["window"], tab, (streamId) => {
          //console.log(streamId, tab);
        });
      }
      return false;
    })
```

And it worked. *I hope this helps*